# Product Inventory going to negative

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

If customer is buying last products from inventory then. it's also accepting order when inventory is out of stock.

and in admin it shows inventory of product in -(negative value).

I don't want to accept order if inventory is 0

Comment: This is a statement, not a question.

Comment: is there any way to prevent - value in inventory @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Share your code from where Inventory is getting subtracted in the code. The error might be over there.

Comment: @Karan Adhikari: Of course: Don't allow customers to order beyond what's in the inventory. Or: Don't substact it from the inventory at time of ordering. Or: When inventory is zero, add the bought amount to what needs to be ordered from the supplier. Etc.

Comment: but i am using default magento and it's happening with default code.@KIKOSoftware